# Weka Invalid Range List at 7-8

Tags: java, attributes, selection, weka

I'm currently having trouble with attribute selection in weka, more specifically the selected Attributes range list when using a Remove filter initialized with the attribute indices calculated by the AttributeSelection class.

The selected attributes (as printed to the standard commandline) are: **4,7-8,19,23**.

All of these exist (I have 23 attributes, 22 numerical and one nominal class attribute with index `numAttributes() - 1`).

So now, when I apply the remove filter (for which I set inverse selection to be true) to my dataset when classifying data, i get the following exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid range list at 7-8.

Does anybody know where this problem might arise from?

If you need code or any other information, feel free to ask, I'm open for every help.

Thanks in advance, 
adurx.

Comment: Please post some code

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I figured out the mistakes by myself: 1.: I used the same classifier object for all classifications for different datasets with different class attributes. 2.: I applied the filter already, since I somehow forgot that the FilteredClassifier in weka filters the data itself (yeah, that was kind of dumb). So it tried to remove the attributes that had already been removed.